# Four sum problem to find tuplets - space complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, space-complexity

I am working on below interview question:

> Given four lists A, B, C, D of integer values, compute how many tuples
> (i, j, k, l) there are such that A[i] + B[j] + C[k] + D[l] is zero.
>
> To make problem a bit easier, all A, B, C, D have same length of N
> where 0 ≤ N ≤ 500. All integers are in the range of -228 to 228 - 1
> and the result is guaranteed to be at most 231 - 1.

Example:

> Input:
>
> A = [ 1, 2]
>
> B = [-2,-1]
>
> C = [-1, 2]
>
> D = [ 0, 2]
>
> Output: 2

Below is the [code](https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum-ii/discuss/93920/Clean-java-solution-O(n2)) and I am not able to understand why the space complexity is O(n^2)? We use only one Map so it should be O(n) space complexity?

```
public int fourSumCount(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C, int[] D) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    for(int i=0; i<C.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<D.length; j++) {
            int sum = C[i] + D[j];
            map.put(sum, map.getOrDefault(sum, 0) + 1);
        }
    }
    
    int res=0;
    for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<B.length; j++) {
            res += map.getOrDefault(-1 * (A[i]+B[j]), 0);
        }
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the length of input  arrays A,B,C,D

if we assume each array with length `N` that means
we have ,

O(NxN) for the first nested loop
O(NxN) for the second nested loop

hence we have O(NxN) + O(NxN) = O(2xN^2)

```
= O(N^2)
```

> We use only one Map so it should be O(n) space complexity?

NO, you are puting into the map O(N^2) times since it is a nested loop

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `C.length = D.length = N`. You have a loop inside loop.
It means, in the first part of the algorithm you call `map.put` function `N*N` times. 
It gives you already `O(N^2)`. As you use the `HashMap` you can assume that `get` and `put` operations "cost" constant time.

The second part more or less the same. It gives you `O(N^2 + N^2) = O(N^2)`.